# How to format sql date (yyyy-mm-dd) to display as just (yyyy) in jsp?

Tags: sql, date, jsp, printing, format

I have an sql entry of a date of birth (dob) that was pulled from query.jsp with jdbc, stored as dob, and sent to results.jsp.  The sql date is in a yyyy-mm-dd format, but I need to display only the year. My current code for this issue:

---

```
<%@ page import="java.text.*" %>

<%
String birthdate = request.getParameter("dob");
SimpleDateFormat yearOnly = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
Date year = yearOnly.parse(birthdate);
%>
```

---

**ERROR Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date**

How can I format my sql date to display only the year portion of the dob?  Should I format in the query.jsp or the results.jsp?

Comment: `String birthdate` should this be `date` data type?

Comment: can you add your full code?I do not see any `java.sql.Date` type in your code

Comment: look here: https://gist.github.com/NKjoep/4344305 might help... if you want to do this in SQL then you have to tell us which dbms palatform as the syntax differs

Answer (score 0):

Avoid scriptlets in your JSP.

Convert the java.sql.Date to a java.util.Date:

```
java.util.Date newDate = new Date(rs.getDate("MY_COLUMN").getTime());
```

Declare a reference to the JSP formatting library at the top of your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "fmt" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

and use the formatDate tag to output your date:

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern = "yyyy" value = "${dob}" /></p>
```

where dob is your request scoped attribute referenced via JSP EL.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatdate_tag.htm